# crash while trying to move row in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

im moving the row in a section in the following case:

```
 if tableView.numberOfSections > 1 {
                        if self.completedView.isExpended {
                            self.updateTable(tableView, action: {
                                tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1))
                            }, completion: { [weak self] in
                                ....
                            })
                        }
```

im getting a crash on crashlytics, that the app is crashing at the line :

```
tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1))
```

im getting the following error:

```
UITableView internal inconsistency: encountered out of bounds global row index while preparing batch updates (oldRow=2, oldGlobalRowCount=2)
```

anyone has an idea what the error could be? thanks

Comment: Please also show your `UITableViewDataSource` implementation. Most likely, your datasource and table get out of sync somewhere because you are either forgetting to update the data source or forgetting to update the table when you update the data source.

Comment: @naglerrr which function do you want me exactly to show?

Comment: try to surround `tableView.beginUpdate()` and `tableView.endUpdate()`